# Reading Two Files and Writing To One File Using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently using Python 3 on Ubuntu 18.04.  I'm not a programmer by any means and I'm not asking for a code review, however, I'm having an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

I have 1 text file named `content.txt` that I'm reading lines from.
I have 1 text file named `standard.txt` that I'm reading lines from.
I have 1text file named `outfile.txt` that I'm writing to.

```
content = open("content.txt", "r").readlines()
standard = open("standard.txt", "r").readlines()
outfile = "outfile.txt"
outfile_set = set()
with open(outfile, "w") as f:
    for line in content:
        if line not in standard:
            outfile_set.add(line)
    f.writelines(sorted(outfile_set))
```

I'm not sure where to put the following line though.  My for loop nesting may all be off:

```
f.write("\nNo New Content")
```

Any code examples to make this work would be most appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: write `no new content` is the case when line in standard ? right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand good you whant to add outfile_set if this is not empty to the outfile or add the string "\nNo New Content"

Replace the line

```
f.writelines(sorted(outfile_set))
```

to

```
if any(outfile_set):
    f.writelines(sorted(outfile_set))
else:
    f.write("\nNo New Content")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to write "No new content" to the file if every line in content is in standard. So you might do something like:

```
with open(outfile, "w") as f:
    for line in content:
        if line not in standard:
            outfile_set.add(line)
    if len(outfile_set) > 0:
        f.writelines(sorted(outfile_set))
    else:
        f.write("\nNo New Content")
```

Your original code was almost there!

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your runtime a lot by using [set/frozenset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
with open("content.txt", "r") as f:
    content = frozenset(f.readlines())  # only get distinct values from file
with open("standard.txt", "r") as f:
    standard = frozenset(f.readlines()) # only get distinct values from file

# only keep whats in content but not in standard
outfile_set = sorted(content-standard) # set difference, no loops or tests needed


with open ("outfile.txt","w") as outfile:
    if outfile_set:   
        outfile.writelines(sorted(outfile_set))
    else:   
        outfile.write("\nNo New Content")
```

You can read more about it here:

- [set operator list (python 2 - but valid for 3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) - can't find this overview in py3 doku
- [set difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference)

---

Demo:

```
# Create files
with open("content.txt", "w") as f:
    for n in map(str,range(1,10)):     # use range(1,10,2) for no changes
        f.writelines(n+"\n") 
with open("standard.txt", "w") as f:
    for n in map(str,range(1,10,2)): 
        f.writelines(n+"\n") 

# Process files:
with open("content.txt", "r") as f:
    content = set(f.readlines()) 
with open("standard.txt", "r") as f:
    standard = set(f.readlines())

# only keep whats in content but not in standard
outfile_set = sorted(content-standard)  

with open ("outfile.txt","w") as outfile:
    if outfile_set:
        outfile.writelines(sorted(outfile_set))
    else:
        outfile.write("\nNo New Content")

with open ("outfile.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
8
```

or

```
No New Content
```